# Remove null rows from spark query result

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I am using Scala 2.11 and my spark version is 2.4.4. 
I have below query from bunch of json files.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, ArrayType, FloatType, TimestampType}

val schema = 
  StructType(
  List(
    StructField("SMS",StringType,false),
    StructField("SMSCorrupt", StringType, false)
  ))

val SMSCorruptDF =  spark.read
  .schema(schema)
  .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
  .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "SMSCorrupt")
  .json("/mnt/UbiqLog4UCI/14_F/log_1-6-2014.txt")
  //.na.drop()

display(SMSCorruptDF)
```

My result is something like below image :

[image]

I need to have just the rows where at least one of my columns has data. when i ran my query with .na.drop() result is empty.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is shown below:

```
scala> val df = Seq((null, Some(2)), (Some("a"), Some(4)), (Some("c"), Some(5)), (Some("b"), null),(null,null)).toDF("A", "B")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A: string, B: int]

scala> df.show
+----+----+
|   A|   B|
+----+----+
|null|   2|
|   a|   4|
|   c|   5|
|   b|null|
|null|null|
+----+----+


scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> val cond = df.columns.map(x => col(x).isNotNull).reduce(_ || _)
cond: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = ((A IS NOT NULL) OR (B IS NOT NULL))

scala> df.filter(cond).show
+----+----+
|   A|   B|
+----+----+
|null|   2|
|   a|   4|
|   c|   5|
|   b|null|
+----+----+
```

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: why did you need to "reduce(_ || _)"?

Comment: @ArdalanShahgholi we need `reduce(_ || _)` to combine the rows which have do not have null in any of column. If we will do `reduce(_ && _)`, then only rows having all non null would be present.

Comment: If i want to have the rows where A has value what should i write?

Comment: @ArdalanShahgholi you will write `reduce((a,b) => a)`. It will give rows where A has values.

Comment: I wrote this but did not work
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val cond = df.columns.map(x => col(x).isNotNull).reduce((a,b) => a)
df.filter(cond).show

Comment: @ArdalanShahgholi what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A: string, B: int]
cond: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = (A IS NOT NULL)

Comment: @ArdalanShahgholi That is not an error. It is just logging by spark. Spark has converted your query internally and logged. It can be seen in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see why you can't just use

```
df.na.drop(how="all")
```